# Почему на touch устройствах верстка перестаёт центрироватся и съезжает влево

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Почему на touch устройствах верстка перестаёт центрироватся и съезжает влево?

https://xn--80aah4bechect6l.xn--p1ai/chemistry/index.html

даже не центрируются margin:0 auto не работает, уже мозг сломал в чём дело, подскажите или киньте ссылку где почитать о такой проблеме

Answer (score 1):

У вас верстка так себя ведет, потому что:

1. У вас width задан. На экране в 544px у вас блоки с заданной шириной 1920px и т.п. По сути у вас нет адаптива. Поэтому такое поведение.
2. Нет мета тега для viewport и т.п.

Советую посмотреть тут: [ссылка](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверить meta тег viewport должно быть

   ```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ```

Если нет вообще добавить строку выше.

2. Возможно после добавления строки всё будет некрасиво, т.к. нет стилей для моб. устройств. В этом случае есть выход добавить view port с фиксированной шириной в px

значения в px - в вашем случае это 1200px

```
<meta name="viewport" content="1200px">
```